# MySQL Query to insert ialue into a column based on value of another column

Tags: mysql

The following query will simply replace the text of each options field with "|| Heavy Duty Insert" if the corresponding features field contains "Key-Loc", right?

```
INSERT INTO `products`(`options`) VALUES ('|| Heavy Duty Insert') 
      WHERE `features` LIKE '%Key-Loc%'
```

How do I add "|| Heavy Duty Insert" to the end of the string contained in the options field where the features field contains "Key-Loc"?

Comment: thats called update not insert i.e. `update products set options = '|| Heavy Duty Insert' where features LIKE '%Key-Loc%'`

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty please put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with update command as

```
update products 
set options = '|| Heavy Duty Insert'
where features LIKE '%Key-Loc%'
```